# Configuring GeoNetwork data directory

Tags: geonetwork

I have a data of older geonetwork catalog stored in `/var/lib/geonetwork_data`. I need to configure the data directory in geonetwork 4.0.5, but I can't find in which file to do it. I have set `geonetwork.dir` in the `web.xml` file but it does not recognize the data directory.

Which file should I set the geonetwork data directory?

Comment: do you have any environment variables pointing at the old location?

Comment: I do not have variables configured, in the geonetwork administration graphical interface the value that appears for the data folder is /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/portal/WEB-INF/ data/data/metadata_data

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Linux...
For example Ubuntu

File: `/etc/default/tomcat9`

Entry: `JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dgeonetwork.dir=/var/lib/geonetwork_data"`

And don't forget to edit `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tomcat9.service`, add `ReadWritePaths /var/lib/geonetwork_data` because tomcat is sandboxed too